# Open .csv file generated in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, export-to-csv

I'm creating a **.csv** file you need and when you save or create, open immediately.

This my Code, but it does not work.

```
public void generateCsvFile(String file, ArrayList<Row> list) {
    try {
        OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput(file, Activity.MODE_PRIVATE));

        writer.append("Matricula");
        writer.append(',');
        writer.append("Fecha Entrada");
        writer.append(',');
        writer.append("Fecha Salida");

        writer.append('\n');

        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            Row r = list.get(i);

            writer.append(r.getMatricula());
            writer.append(',');
            writer.append(r.getFechain() + " " + r.getHorain());
            writer.append(',');
            writer.append(r.getFechaout() + " " + r.getHoraout());
            writer.append('\n');
        }

        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
}
```

any ideas?

regards
Alex

Comment: Context.openFileInput() is the corollary to Context.openFileOutput(). More details here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've done this: [writer.flush (); writer.close (); openFileInput (file)] does not work,??